# JQuery Mobile click event not working depending on element location within HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to build a collapsible-set grid, which shows information dynamically, as you click on each collapsed grid, it should do some stuff to get the desired data, then generate some HTML code and insert it dynamically within that grid.
The problem is, disregarding WS calls and all that stuff, when I make a simple test to insert some simple HTML code within that DIV, I discovered click event is not working. After performing several tests, I found click event will work only if I place the button within the data-role="content" DIV, but outside the ddata-role="collapsible-set" DIV. I don't know why but that's exactly what's happening.
Here's a fiddle with the code for my document's body:

```
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="home">
        <div data-role="content">
            <a href="#" data-role="button" id="btnPrueba">Test button</a>
            <div data-role="collapsible-set" id="setAllCategory" data-content-theme="d">
                <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-d" data-expanded-icon="arrow-u"
                id="setCategory1">
                     <h1><label>Food</label>
                    <a data-role="button" id="btnAddSubCat1" name="btnAddSubCat1"  data-rel="popup"  href="#" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="notext" style="float:right;" ><a/></h1>

                    <div id="setCategoryContent1"></div>
                </div>
                <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-d" data-expanded-icon="arrow-u"
                id="setCategory2">
                     <h1><label>Dress</label>
                    <a data-role="button" id="btnAddSubCat2" name="btnAddSubCat2"  data-rel="popup"  href="#" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="notext" style="float:right;" ><a/></h1>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yaguarete79/nggtfLog/

Comment: Just re edit your [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/anthonypagaycarbon/t368Ly69/), something working fine but I'm still confused of what your trying to do.

Comment: Thank you Anthony Carbon, what I was trying to do was to dynamically insert some html content within a grid. I'm sorry I misplaced JavaScript in the CSS box. But I guess you mean I have the same JS code twice for the working example and twice for the non working example. I just wanted to show all scenarios I'd tried. ezanker solved it right away though, but thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to add a button, you can use the collapsibles **[expand event](http://api.jquerymobile.com/collapsible/#event-expand)** to catch when the user expands it.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#home", function () {

    var subCatObject = '<div class="ui-grid-b">';
    subCatObject += '<div class="ui-block-a"><label>Hi</label></div>';
    subCatObject += '<div class="ui-block-b"><a href="#" data-role="button" data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="edit"></a></div>';
    subCatObject += '<div class="ui-block-c"><a href="#" data-role="button" data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="delete"></a></div>';
    subCatObject += '</div>';

    $("#setCategory1").on("collapsibleexpand", function (event, ui) {
        $("#setCategoryContent1").html(subCatObject).enhanceWithin();
    });


});
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/nggtfLog/2/)**

Comment: Works like a charm, @ezanker ! I'll read it further to see what I was missing. I think your approach is cleaner. Thank you!!!